# Change a style border of LightBox Primefaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I use PrimeFaces 1.1 with JSF 1.2.
I need to change the style of PrimeFaces `<p:lightBox>` overlay that has a black border to blue, but the `style` attribute of the component don't change the overlay, but only the link from which the lightbox is been called.

```
<p:lightBox width="50%" height="25%" 
    style="border: 5px; border-style: solid; border-color: blue;">
    <h:outputLink value="#" title="Leo Messi" >
        <h:outputText value="The Messiah"/>
    </h:outputLink>

    <f:facet name="inline">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/barca/messi.jpg" />
            <h:outputText style="color:#FFFFFF"
                value="Messi is an unusual player. He is highly creative, and has the skills to take on defenders with ease. He is a versatile left-footed player who can play either in the middle or on either wing, or even as a centre forward.
                Although he is quite short, he is so fast and physically strong that he can cope with larger opponents. He is incredibly powerful, and a specialist in such dead ball situations as corners, free kicks and penalties.
                Leo Messi is cool-headed and able to assume several responsibilities in times of need. He is a player who is destined to have a very successful career in football."></h:outputText>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </f:facet>
</p:lightBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong that is the `<a>` tag generated. I don't know if you can add any attributes to lightbox's `<div>`.

I don't have your HTML code generated, but you can do this:

1. Use Google Chrome to inspect lightbox (right click on lightbox and inspect element) to view `<div>`'s class.
2. Add a new "onclick" attribute to `<a>` and using javascript restyle the elements...

But you should modify primefaces's css from the jar file... I don't find the javascript method elegant...

Comment: Thks alex for your replay, this is link that you can find the html code generated: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/lightBoxExternal.jsf

Comment: I make some modification on the css file that is embedded in the primefaces jar, but when i include the new jar in the project, the primefaces API does not work

Comment: @ANIS BOULILA hei.. do not do like this... just create a new css and include in your page (where the link is located)... the css properties from primefaces should be overwritten by your css file

Comment: Alex!! the styleclass and style attributes of <p:lightbox> don't make change on the lightbox but on the link from which the lightbox is been called

Comment: Yes... But don't add the style to a tag... Create a new css file and include it in the page

Comment: No result<ui:define name="head">
   
<p:resources/>
    <style type="text/css">
.colorbox .cboxContent .cboxLoadedContent{
padding: 0px;
background: red;
}
.cboxTitle{color: red;}
</style>
</ui:define>

Comment: hmm.. what if you just open the jar as zip archive and modify that css as you said before? I don't know any other elegant solution (one might be to add an event handler on lightbox link and modify css using javascript...

Comment: Thanks Alex. In this case of lightbox component i modified the jar but i hope that i don't find styling problem with other primefaces component:)